# How to tell if ecommerce website is Woocommerce or Shopify or none?

Tags: php, woocommerce, shopify

I'm in search of a foolproof method via code to tell if an ecommerce platform id running on woocommerce or shopify.

ATM, I came up with the code below that checks if there's a URL with "wp-admin" or "admin", but its not foolproof.

```
  $url1 = "https://www." . $_POST['domain'] . "/wp-admin";
     $url2 = "https://www." . $_POST['domain'] . "/admin";

     // Use get_header() function

     $headers1 = @get_headers($url1);
     $headers2 = @get_headers($url2);

     // Use conditio to check existence of URL

     if($headers1 && strpos($headers1[0], '200'))
     {
         $eCommercePlatform = "WordPress/Woocommerce";
     }
     elseif($headers2 && strpos($headers2[0], '200'))
     {
        $eCommercePlatform = "Shopify";
     }
     else
     {
        $eCommercePlatform = "Not Shopify or Woocommerce";
     }
```

Any other good hacks/suggestions?

Comment: `wp-admin` should always be some sort of Wordpress, but `admin` is a bit of a universal login/term, so wouldn't be just Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like that:

```
// Mimic the browser
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');

$headers = @get_headers($url, 1);

if (isset($headers['X-Shopify-Stage'])) {
    $eCommercePlatform = "Shopify";
} elseif (!empty($headers['X-Powered-By']) && $headers['X-Powered-By'] == 'WP Engine') {
    $eCommercePlatform = "WordPress/Woocommerce";
} else {
    $eCommercePlatform = "Not Shopify or Woocommerce";
}
```

**Explanation**:

Checking the `/wp-admin` path seems is not the best way to detect WordPress as on the first WP website I tested - it returned **403 Forbidden**. I assume others may do the same for security purposes.

I found that all Shopify sites return `X-Shopify-Stage` header (at least for the time being) which can be used.

Comment: X-Powered-By returns "PHP/x.x.x" now for WooCommerce sites. X-Shopify-Stage still works for Shopify (2021).